# Change size and position of custom handle in bootstrap slider

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a bootstrap slider with custom handle shape. In jquery doc we can found parameter like `handle: 'custom'`, but how to define this custom handle ? 
I found solution in css like that :

```
<div id="divswipe" style="position: fixed;bottom: 80px;width:100%">
  <input id="swipe" type="text" style="width: 100%" data-slider-handle="custom">
</div>

<style>
  .slider-handle.custom {
    background: transparent none;
    }

.slider-handle.custom::before {
    line-height: 80px;
    font-size: 20px;
    content: url('apps/balayage/img/swipe_design2.png');
}
</style>
```

It works but how to define position and size of that ? Actualy, it's like that :
[my handle shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F44IX.png)
and I want something like that : [what I'd like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bc6s.png)